# findById jpa with postgresql, repeat elements

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an object (tailor), with this two variables:

```
public class Tailor {
......
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "tailor_availability", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_tailor"))
    @Column( name = "availability")
    private Set<String> availability;
        
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Specialties.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "tailor_specialties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_tailor"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "price", column = @Column(name = "price"))
    })
.....
}
    private Set<Specialties> specialties;
```

The object Specialties is related to tailor:

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "specialties")
public class Specialties {
    @Column(name = "name")  
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "price")  
    private String price;

}
```

When I make a call in my Service to get a tailor:

```
    @Override
    public Tailor getATailor(String tailorId) {
        return repository.findById(Long.valueOf(tailorId)).orElse(null);
    }
```

It returns all atributes good, but with Specialties it returns:

```
        {
            "name": "cremallera",
            "price": "7"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bajos falda",
            "price": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bajos falda",
            "price": "10"
        },
      ....... continuos
```

When it would be:

```
        {
            "name": "cremallera",
            "price": "7"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bajos falda",
            "price": "10"
        }
```

In H2 database works, but un postgrestql doesn't work and I don't know why.